# Interpolate data for irregular time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I try to interpolate this meterValue, full csv here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18cwtw-chAB-FqqCesXZJ-6NB6eHFJlgQ

```
localminute,dataid,meter_value
2015-10-03 09:51:53,6578,157806
2015-10-13 13:41:49,6578,158086
:
:
2016-01-17 16:00:33,6578,164544  #end of meter_value data for ID=6578
```

Based on what @G. Grothendieck, suggested, and I got error at z.interpolate (merging data)

```
D6578z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv")[,2]
D6578zd <- to.daily(D6578z)[,4]
#Warning messages:
                #1: In zoo(xx, order.by = index(x), ...) : some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
                #2: In zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

     test_6578t <- time(D6578zd)

     plot(D6578zd,type="p",xaxt="n", pch=19, col="blue",cex=1.5)

     diff(test_6578t) 

     t.daily6578 <- seq(from =min(test_6578t),to=max(test_6578t),by="1 day")

     dummy6578 <- zoo(,t.daily6578) 

     z.interpolated <- merge(D6578zd,dummy6578,all=TRUE)
        *#Error in merge.zoo(D6578zd, dummy6578, all = TRUE) :  series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series*
```

**Solution of R code for one hour time difference in interpolated data provided by @G. Grothendieck, as below.**

Hi @G. Grothendieck, Thanks for solution code. I have some questions to clarify with you regarding about your code.

```
  `line1: to.hour <- function(x) as.POSIXct(trunc(as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01"), "hour"))

    line2: z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = to.hour, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))`

         `line3: zz <- na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z)))`

        `line4: time(zz) <- as.POSIXct(time(zz), origin = "1970-01-01")`
```

> in line1, why “as.POSIXct” before `trunc(as.POSIXct(x,origin
>   =”1970-01-01”)?
>   I understand that "trunc" function round up the datetime value.
>
> In line2, What does this code mean “FUN=to.hour, aggregate
>   =function(x) tail (x,1)” work?
>
> As I could not understand what is tail(x,1).  I extracted the `z`
>   function in csv file, I observed that only dataid and meter_value
>   columns are generated when ‘read.csv.zoo’ function is used.
>
> In line3, I understand that, `zz` function gives interpolated data 
>   but I didn’t fully understand the code “na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z)))” ,
>   since `z` is already zoo series after read.csv.zoo, why we still have
>   to use “as.zoo” and “as.ts” in “na.approx” line?
>
> what is the difference between zoo and zooreg series?
>
> In line4, “time(zz)” is the index of “zz” function?

Thanks in advance your explanation.

I could plot the interpolated data with time difference=1hour. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file in using `read.csv.zoo` converting to `Date` class aggregating duplicate dates such that the last one is used.  Then convert to `ts` and back to zoo which will fill in empty days with NAs.  Now use `na.approx` to fill in the NA values. Since `ts` cannot represent `Date` class the resulting series will have numbers representing dates so convert them back.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = as.Date, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
zz <- na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z)))
time(zz) <- as.Date(time(zz))
```

In comments there was a claim that there are holes in the ouptut but that is not the case.  The difference between successive times is identically 1 and there are no NAs.

```
table(diff(time(zz)))
##   1 
## 106 

any(is.na(zz)) 
## [1] FALSE

any(is.na(time(zz)))
## [1] FALSE
```

Here is an example of doing this for one hour instead of one day differences.

```
to.hour <- function(x) as.POSIXct(trunc(as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01"), "hour"))
z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = to.hour, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
zz <- na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z)))
time(zz) <- as.POSIXct(time(zz), origin = "1970-01-01")

plot(zz[, 2], type = "p", pch = ".")
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Dont mind, I dont understand how this two lines works. Please correct me, if I am wrong. 
`zd <- to.daily(z)[, 4]` <- could you explain what does this line mean? what i observed is zd gives zoo’ series from 2015-10-01 to 2016-03-31, Data: int [1:182]

`z <- read.csv.zoo("test_2034.csv")[, 2]  # extract only column name =mtervalue?`

Comment: I tried for another dataID csv file(https://drive.google.com/open?id=18cwtw-chAB-FqqCesXZJ-6NB6eHFJlgQ Read.csv.zoo has no error but I got error in converting regular series. When I run this code: `D6578zd <- to.daily(D6578z)[,4]`
Warning messages:
1: In zoo(xx, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
2: In zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Comment: my code flow for interpolating another data  set is in my question above. where I got error in merging

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck, if you dont mind, may I know, how does this code mean `function(x) tail(x, 1))[, 2]` in aggregate function.
z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = as.Date, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
“FUN= as.Date” converting to Date class, 
As i run only `function(x) tail(x, 1))[, 2]` gives error in R-console

Comment: As you can see the plot in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lVVtCphuGhnO7kzHSl76u8Q0u03U_Qxf , Seems like z.interpolated data points, are not fully filled in the existing data (red points in the plot). Is there any possible to a dd hh:mm:ss ? So that all the datas can interpolate.  time difference `diff(time_zooNA)` will be either 15mins interval or 30mins?

Comment: ,I added the plot (output of your solution code), in my question post. I would like to get more interpolated points (more red dots in the plot). And also my localminute in dataset are in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, instead of having `FUN=as.date`, is it possible to change the vector `z` to date & time type?  Lastly, your solution code -`diff(time(zz))` gives time difference in 1 day, is it possible to get the time difference in hours?

Comment: Yup, I agree that, there is no holes in your interpolated codes.  Is it possible to change this code to `z <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = as.DateTime, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))` , as I would like to get time differences =1 hour

Comment: I have added a one hour example.

Comment: Thanks for one hour example. I could got error that, could not plot the one hour interpolated data. I added in my question post.

Comment: As the error message says points is used for a single series, not multiple series.

Comment: I have added a plot statement.

Comment: how should I remove the dataID column? "dataID" column has been in part of `z1` code. 
`z1 <- read.csv.zoo("test_6578.csv", FUN = to.hour, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))`

Comment: If z is a zoo series with 2 columns then z[, 2] is the second series only.

Comment: Thanks alot for help, @G. Grothendieck, I can plot without error. Next part, will be forecasting. I updated, in my question post.

Comment: hi  @G. Grothendieck, I have some questions regarding about your solution code, I have updated in my question (main) post. Would you mind, to help clear my doubts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) trunc produces a POSIXlt rather than POSIXct so after trunc it must be converted to POSIXct. (2) See ?read.zoo (3) ts class only supports regularly spaced series whereas zoo also supports irregularly spaced ones so by converting from zoo to ts and back again we get a regularly spaced zoo series.  Also see ?zooreg (4) zz is a zoo series, not a function, and time(zz) <- ... sets its index, i.e. its times.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. how about this `aggregate =function(x) tail (x,1)` ? as i tried to see `?function(x) tail(x,1)` but only shows function defination. `?tail(x,1)` shows that it returns the last parts of a vector, matrix, table, data frame or function. `?aggregate` didnt show how this function works with `tail` in R documentation. Would you mind, to share what does `aggregate =function(x) tail (x,1)`  means in the code?  Thanks again for help

Comment: When using ? you have to look up the function, not the argument.  aggregate= is an argument to read.csv.zoo so you would look at ?read.csv.zoo

Comment: Referring to your solution code: I am trying to merge these two functions  `zz` and `time(zz)` but I got error, `z.interpolated <- merge(time(z),zz)
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Gb`
Is there any way to merge both functions for large data set?

Comment: One is a zoo series and one is a POSIXct vector so you can't merge them.  You could do this: `merge(zz, zoo(, time(z)))`.

Comment: I could only see two columns: dataID and meter_value ,after merge using this code `merge(zz, zoo(, time(zz)))`, there is no error but, the local minute is not in the merge.

Comment: Read `?merge.zoo`